# Setting default Scale when printing

Tags: html, html-table, media-queries

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vZsa.jpg

My table fits perfectly if I set the scale to minimum somewhat around 60. But by default it is 100. What can I do to change the scale maybe using `@media print`?

My problem is same as this question:-

[scale html table before printing using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757370/scale-html-table-before-printing-using-css)

I was wondering if there was a better solution to this?